# filter out duplicate attributes from list

Tags: python, list, filter, attributes

I would like to filter a list by one of its attribute values, with the result that I get a list where that attribute value is unique.

I currently do this using a function

```
def filter_function(self):
    filtered = []
    for data in self.list_of_data:
        exist = False
        for f in filtered:
            if data.val1 == f.val1:
                exist = True

        if not exist:
            filtered.append(data)
    return filtered
```

where self.list_of_data is a list that I want to filter out. 
Is it possible to do this using a map or filter function using lambda?

here data is an object, e.g.

```
class Data(object):
    def __init__(self)
        self.val1
        self.val2
        ...
```

So in other words, is it possible to use a filter function to filter out alle the data object where ´val1´ is e.g. equal to 5, leaving ´vals´ as a ´wildcard´?

For example:

```
  filter( lamda x: f(x), [ { 'val1': 5, 'val2': 2}, { 'val1': 5, 'val2': 3}, { 'val1': 2, 'val2': 2}, { 'val1': 2, 'val2': 3}] )
```

should five gives

```
  [ { 'val1': 5, 'val2': 2}, { 'val1': 5, 'val2': 3}]
```

where f(x) filters out all the object where its val1 is NOT 5?

Comment: Have you tried to convert list to set and then back to a list?

Comment: im not clear on whats the rule for filtering

Comment: @Urb f(x) filters out all the object where its val1 is NOT 5?

Answer (score 1):

[Sets in Python](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set) are great for filtering duplicates.

If you are starting with a list, just convert to a set:

```
>>> lst = [1,1,2,3,4,5]
>>> set(lst)
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
>>> my_set = set(lst)
>>> revised_lst = list(my_set)
>>> revised_lst
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

That gets rid of the duplicates. Then, convert back to a list if needed:

Answer (score 0):

im assuming you got something like that:

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
```

to extract the values u can do:

`>>> test().__dict__`

output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

and from here you can apply `set` like i showed below

You could use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

```
list = [1,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,6,7]

print set(list)
```

output:

```
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

you could also filter you list with another:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
filter = [2,5,7]

print set(list) & set(filter)
```

output:

```
set([2,5])
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to metion there are other attributes in mij data other than value.. I have edited my question

Comment: @Kevinw1983 what do you mean, can you give example to how the data looks like?

Comment: class Data(object):
                self.val
                elf.val_one
               self.val_two
               ...

Comment: Ah understood. But, inyour example of test with atributes ´a´ and ´b´ using sets. if I have a list of test objects with different values for atributes ´a´ and ´b´, Is it possible to filter out alle the test object where ´a´ is e.g. equal to 5, leaving ´b´ as a ´wildcard´?

Comment: for example:
filter( lamda x: f(x), [ {  'a': 5, 'b': 2}, {  'a': 5, 'b': 3}, {  'a': 2, 'b': 2}, {  'a': 2, 'b': 3}] ) should five gives [ {  'a': 5, 'b': 2}, {  'a': 5, 'b': 3}]

is this even possible?

Comment: @Kevinw1983 yes its possible, update you question with this example. and ill rewrite my answer. so u want to filter any element that contains duplicate a or b ?

Comment: @Kevinw1983 if this answers your initial question, accept it and ask different questions on different thread.